# Regular expression negative match

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't seem to figure out how to compose a regular expression (used in Javascript) that does the following:

Match all strings where the characters after the 4th character do not contain "GP".

Some example strings:

- EDAR - match!
- EDARGP - no match
- EDARDTGPRI - no match
- ECMRNL - match

I'd *love* some help here...

Comment: I'd consume the first four characters and then look for GP.  Is a regex even necessary here?  Why not do something like `"EDARGP".slice(4).indexOf('GP') == -1`?

Comment: That could work, except that I can't change the "code", I can only change the regex string, as the code needs to work with several kinds of input values

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use zero-width assertions:

```
if (subject.match(/^.{4}(?!.*GP)/)) {
    // Successful match
}
```

**Explanation:**

```
"
^        # Assert position at the beginning of the string
.        # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   {4}   # Exactly 4 times
(?!      # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead)
   .     # Match any single character that is not a line break character
      *  # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   GP    # Match the characters “GP” literally
)
"
```

Comment: How did you get this explanation? It looks auto-generated, in which case I'd love to know what tool you've been using.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation. Still not quite sure what the "?!" part does though...

Comment: @user1084524 Negative lookahead assertion. Combined with .* is check whether somewhere after the first four character there is GP. Also remove the $ at the end. Was a typo.

Answer (score 7):

You can use what's called a negative lookahead assertion here. It looks into the string ahead of the location and matches only if the pattern contained is /not/ found. Here is an example regular expression:

```
/^.{4}(?!.*GP)/
```

This matches only if, after the first four characters, the string `GP` is not found.

Answer (score 2):

could do something like this:

```
var str = "EDARDTGPRI";
var test = !(/GP/.test(str.substr(4)));
```

test will return true for matches and false for non.

Comment: @FailedDev thanks but of course you and Dan have the correct answer :P nicely done.

Comment: Do we? Your solution is probably faster not to mention simpler :)

Comment: This is the most efficient solution. Regexen are slow.

Comment: This works, but not in my scenario. The regex string is a variable and the code should work with all regexes. Changing the code is not an option. Thanks anyway!