# Match characters which are not part of captured group or match C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a Regex: `(['"])((?:\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)`

What I want is to match `([{}])` except match from above regex.

I just want to skip match which is part of this: `(['"])((?:\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression negative match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408152/regular-expression-negative-match)

Comment: No. I want combination something like `([{}])(?:(['"])((?:\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1))`, but that's not working.

Comment: This is what I found: `(['"])((?:\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)|([{}])`. This will be in group 4.

Comment: I think the `(['"])((?:\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)` is not what you need if you want to match any single or double quoted string literal, you need `(['"])(?:(?!\\1).)*\1` (see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5b%27%22%5d%29%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5c%5c1%29.%29*%5c1&i=%22..%27..%22%0d%0a%27..%22..%27)). Now, whta are you trying to achieve? Remove all curly braces (`{` and `}`) that are outside `"..."` and `'...'` substrings?

Comment: Yes Exactly. Take all curly braces ({ and }) that are outside "..." and '...', and anything that is not part of string literals.

Comment: This: `(['"])((?:\\1|(?:(?!\1)).)*)(\1)|(?<OpenMatch>[{])|(?<CloseMatch>[}])` is perfect. But now just need to get groups OpenMatch or CloseMatch and ignore all other groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"((['""])(?:(?!\2).)*\2)|[({})]", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%5B%27%22%5D%29%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5C2%29.%29*%5C2%29%7C%5B%28%7B%7D%29%5D&i=%22..%27..%22%20%7B%7D%7D%0D%0A%27..%22..%27%20%29%29%20%28&r=%241). Details:

- `((['"])(?:(?!\2).)*\2)` - Capturing group 1 (`$1` in the replacement pattern refers to this group value): a substring between `'` or `"` chars:

  - `(['"])` - Group 2: `'` or `"`
  - `(?:(?!\2).)*` - zero or more chars, as many as possible, that are not equal to the value captured in Group 2
  - `\2` - same value as in Group 2
- `|` - or
- `[({})]` - a `(`, {`,` }`or`)` char.

See [the C# demo](https://ideone.com/dGWffh):

```cs
var text = "\"..'..\" {}}\n'..\"..' )) (";
var result = Regex.Replace(text, @"((['""])(?:(?!\2).)*\2)|[({})]", "$1", RegexOptions.Singleline);
Console.WriteLine(result);
# => "..'.." 
#    '.."..'
```